# Liferay setModifiedDate does not impact database's modifiedDate

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I need to create a journal article with a 21/12/2012 modification date, in a Java service. Here is [addArticle](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-journal/blob/master/journal-service/src/main/java/com/liferay/journal/service/impl/JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java#L293)'s JavaDoc:

```
 * @param  serviceContext the service context to be applied. Can set the
 *         [...], modification date, [...]
 *         for the web content article.
```

Here is my attempt:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("21/12/2012");
serviceContext.setModifiedDate(date);

// Add article.
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle(
    userId, groupId, folderId, titleMap, descriptionMap,
    xmlContent, structureKey, templateKey, serviceContext);
```

PROBLEM: In the database, the created JournalArticle row's `modifiedDate` is today's date.

What did I do wrong?
Maybe the [addArticle](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/modules/apps/web-experience/journal/com.liferay.journal.api/com/liferay/journal/service/JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.html#addArticle(long,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20double,%20java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File,%20java.util.Map,%20java.lang.String,%20com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContext)) call is considered as the last modification? How to work around that?

Comment: As this is a quite detailed question, you might want to look at the implementation at https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-journal/blob/master/journal-service/src/main/java/com/liferay/journal/service/impl/JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java (choose your version's tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by following code:

```
JournalArticle journalArticle =
     JournalArticleUtil.create(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());
Date now = new Date();
Date modifiedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("21/12/2012");

journalArticle.setUserId(userId);
journalArticle.setGroupId(groupId);
journalArticle.setFolderId(folderId);
journalArticle.setTitleMap(titleMap);
journalArticle.setDescriptionMap(descriptionMap);
journalArticle.setContent(xmlContent);
journalArticle.setStructureId(structureKey);
journalArticle.setTemplateId(templateKey);
journalArticle.setCreateDate(now);
journalArticle.setModifiedDate(modifiedDate);

JournalArticle updatedJournalArticle = JournalArticleUtil.update(journalArticle);
```

**Understanding:**
1. `JournalArticleUtil.create` will return you a new object of `JournalArticle` class.
2. Set properties (focused: `setModifiedDate`) as per your requirement.
3. Invoke `JournalArticleUtil.update` by passing that populated object will store it in database.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("21/12/2012");

// Add article.
JournalArticle article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle(
    userId, groupId, folderId, titleMap, descriptionMap,
    xmlContent, structureKey, templateKey, serviceContext);

article.setModifiedDate(date);

JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateJournalArticle(article);
```

Another way:

You can use the `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addJournalArticle(journalArticle)` method, but you have to create manually the `journalArticle` object:

```
long primaryKey = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(JournalArticle.class.getName());
JournalArticle journalArticle = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.createJournalArticle(primaryKey);

//Set all the journal properties you need...
journalArticle.setGroupId(yourGroupId);
journalArticle.setUserId(yourUserId);
journalArticle.setStructureId(ddmStructureKey);
journalArticle.setTemplateId(ddmTemplateKey);
...

JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addJournalArticle(journalArticle);
```

This is related to Liferay 7 API, but it should works on 6.2 also.

Comment: For performance reasons (migrating tons of content), I would really prefer to a second Liferay/database call. But if there is no other solution I will use this, thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer, check if it is better for you now. Btw there are still two calls to DB :(

Comment: Minor note: In the second code listing, could also add the `setModifiedDate` call? It is trivial, but it is the point of the question after all so better make it 100% clear ^_^

Comment: Also, what is the difference between your two suggested ways: addArticle+updateJournalArticle and createJournalArticle+addJournalArticle?

Comment: Yes, you can set the modifiedDate, it is one of the methods you have. Btw the difference is that with the second way you have to set all the fields of the journal and they are a lot: [JournalArticle JavaDoc](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/modules/apps/web-experience/journal/com.liferay.journal.api/com/liferay/journal/model/JournalArticle.html) . So you should check for each fields if it is required, if it is an id ecc... In the first way instead Liferay will do all the dirty work.

Comment: With `addArticle`+`updateJournalArticle` (the first way) the modification date is set to today's date, not the specified date. `createJournalArticle`+`addJournalArticle` (with a dozen of setXXX) does not create any new row in the JournalArticle database table, strangely.

Comment: Good answer, but its `JournalArticleUtil` instead of `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil`.